# What are set-at-a-time operations and in what situation would processing a set of data be needed to be done by the application program

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, cursors

## Question:

What are set at a time operations and in what situation would processing a set of data be needed to be done by the application program?

Cheers.

Comment: "I know that cursors work at a 'set at a time process' for the DBMS. - Incorrect.

Comment: Any time the application needs to do the same thing to more than one row.

Comment: @Kiwi_Boy: I'm familiar with the pros and cons of cursors.

Comment: So basically a set at a time operation is to retrieve more than one  row(s). If I want to retrieve a set I have to use for example a "SELECT" statement. So a cursor returns a set even though it is looping through every row from start to finish?

Comment: Note that no SQL statement is required to operate only on a single row at a time.

Comment: _"A cursor is basically a query and has parameters"_ A cursor is an iterator through the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the relevant data is in an Oracle database then the processing never *requires* procedural code.

Oracle SQL has many methods for processing data, such as inline views, analytic functions, `MODEL` clauses, `WITH` clauses, etc.  Combining those can solve any programming problem.  That doesn't necessarily mean everything should be done in a single SQL statement.  As you get comfortable with those features your SQL statements will get larger and faster, and the overall amount of code will get smaller.  But there's always a point where regular old procedural code makes more sense.

---

Your original statement is partially correct: "cursors work at a 'set at a time process' for the DBMS."  Row-by-row processing with a cursor is usually the opposite of set-based processing.  But Oracle can still do a few things to make parts of the process set-based.

For example, look at this simple code to join an EMPLOYEE and DEPARTMENT tables and print the results.

```
begin
    for employee_and_departments in
    (
        select employee.employee_name, department.department_name
        from employee
        join department
            on employee.department_id = department.department_id
        order by employee_name
    ) loop
        dbms_output.put_line(employee.employee_name||', '||
            department.department_name);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

This is *not* how the anonymous block is processed:

```
For each row:
    1) Use index to retrieve one employee record, in order
    2) Use index to lookup relevant row in department record
    3) return one row
    4) print one result
```

The details vary depending on the execution plan, but this is a more likely way to process the anonymous block:

```
1) Hash the department table and store it in memory
2) Join it with employee table
3) Order results
4) Retrieve 100 rows at a time, and for each row:
    4a) Print one result
```

SQL operations and data retrieval are frequently done in bulk even when not requested.  Part of the statement is still done row-by-row, but most of the heavy lifting is automatically done in batches.  There is still room for massive improvement when procedural PL/SQL is converted to declarative SQL.  But a lot of code benefits from set-based processing without knowing it.